# Libre Office Calc copy and doubles values to other column

Tags: libreoffice-calc

i have in Libreoffice Calc column A eg

```
1
5
25
7
```

and i want create column B with some copy method to

```
1
1
5
5
25
25
7
7
```

it has to be some simple solution, but i dont find it :(

thanks for answer

Answer just under this question is for Excel, but i need for LibreOffice Calc (my fault, i ask for excel earlier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adapt Scott Craner's answer for LO Calc, the formula in B1 should be:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-1)/2)+1)
```

Or this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT((ROW()-1)/2)+1,1))
```

[image: spreadsheet result]

Documentation: [INDEX](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDEX), [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT), [ADDRESS](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ADDRESS), [ROW](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ROW).

Answer (score 3):

In B1:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1)
```

And copy/drag down

Change the `/2` to the number of time you want repeated.

Change the `+1` to the row number where your data starts in that column.

[image]

Comment: super...but my fault, i wrote Excel and have i LibreOffice Calc..and there report an Error508

Comment: They are not the same thing.  As you see some formulas work in one and not another.  Please remove the Excel tag and put in the libreoffice tag so those who know that app can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution alone, but Scott help me too much..thanks

```
=INDEX(A:A;ROUND(ROW(A1)/2);1)
```